# Use the definition of $\ln(x)$ as an integral to show that $f(x)=\frac{ln(x)}{x^2} \leq 1/x$ for all $x\geq 1$.

Tags: integration, logarithms

As the title says, if we let $$f(x)=\frac{ln(x)}{x^2}$$

I know that $$ln(x)=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} dt$$
Since $x^2 >0$ we can rewrite the question as $ln(x) \lt x$ $\forall$ $x\ge1$

How do we approach this? The one hint we have is to bound the integral with an upper sum, but that's just confusing me further.

Is it as simple as stating that the definition itself implies that $$\frac{1}{x}=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} dt$$ and that $$\frac{1}{x} \lt x$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has $$\log x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} \leq \int_1^x dt = x-1 < x$$ Since $x\geq 1$, dividing by $x^2$ preserves the inequality.

Comment: I must be missing something because I thought int_1^x dt = x-1?

Comment: @DwayneH That's what I have :)

Comment: Ah yep. I was reading it as though the two inequalities were equal to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: There's a fundamental inequality involving integrals that says

$$\left | \int_a^b f(t)\, dt \right | \leq (b-a) \cdot \max\{\left | f(t) \right |\,; \, t \in (a,b)\}$$

Can you think of how to use it?

Comment: I have heard of an inequality regarding this, but I have to say the formula you wrote seems a bit foreign to me. Mainly everything after max, is that the max of a set or something?

Comment: $\max$ is always the maximum of a set, it is always taken over a set (just like $\sup$). Sometimes, however it is written in a more compact form, such as

$$\max_{t \in (a,b)}\left | f(t) \right |$$

The inequality is pretty intuitive. Thinking about the integram as some sort of 'continuous/infinitesimal' sum (Riemann sum), it boils down to 'the integral certainly can't be more than the continuous sum of the maximum of the integrand'.

Comment: Out of curiousity is there a formal name for this inequality? I've looked through the notes for the course and I can't see anything similar. Looking online it looks almost like the Mean Value Theorem, but it's still a tiny bit different.

Comment: Hummm, I don't think it has a specific name. Either that, or I don't know of it.

Comment: You don't want the absolute value. Consider $f(x) = -1$. Furthermore, the inequality assumes $f$ attains a maximum. You might want to add the hypothesis of continuity

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 The absolute value is okay for the purposes of this question since the integrand never changes sign. On the $\max$ you are correct; it should be changed to $\sup$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $1\le t\le x$, then $\frac{1}{x}\le\frac{1}{t}\le 1$.

Therefore, we find that

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt \le x-1 \tag 1$$

In fact, $(1)$ is true for all $x>0$.

Finally, we have

$$\frac{x-1}{x^3}\le \frac{1}{x^2}\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt\le \frac{x-1}{x^2}<\frac1x$$

for all $x>0$

Comment: I can follow this, but it seems weird that your solution works for all x > 0 when the question mentions proving for all x >= 1. Obviously the former implies the latter, but that gap of numbers between 0 and 1 makes me feel like this isn't what they want.

Comment: Well, simply disregard investigating for $0<x<1$.  Then, all is fine.  ;-))

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to write
$\ln(1+x)
=\int_1^{1+x} \dfrac{dt}{t}
$
so the inequalities become
$\dfrac{x}{1+x}
\le \ln(1+x)
\le x
$
or,
putting 
$x-1$ for $x$,
$\dfrac{x-1}{x}
\le\ln(x)
\le x-1
$.

Dividing by
$x^2
$,
$\dfrac{x-1}{x^3}
\le \dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^2}
\le \dfrac{x-1}{x^2}
\lt \dfrac1{x}
$.

Note that
this would probably be used
for $x$ near $1$,
so there is no worry
about the lower bound
blowing up.